# How to Get the length of the Characters in grid using Jquery in C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to get the number of characters in Grid from the below Jquery script

Even though i tried by length(data) it shows that length is  a property not a function after removing function the number of charaters are show as 0

```
{
         "sDefaultContent": "", "data": "fld_output_value", "width": 90, "title": "Output Length", render: function (data, string, full, meta) {
                            return length;
                        }
                    },
```

after updating my code it's

```
{
         "sDefaultContent": "", "data": "fld_output_value", "width": 90, "title": "Output Length", render: function (data, string, full, meta) {
                            return data.length;
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: try `data.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @R4ncid said its

`data.length`